# Русские символы в POST запросе С++ Builder 5

Tags: c++, post, c++builder

Необходимо отправить в *POST* запросе русские символы. Среда разработки - *С++ Builder 5*. Для отправки использую `СppWebBrowser` (необходимо реализовать запрос именно через этот компонент).

Код:

```
AnsiString asPostData = "usr="+user+"&pass="+pass+"";

LPSAFEARRAY psa = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_UI1, 0, asPostData.Length());
if( psa )
{
    void *pvdata = NULL;
    SafeArrayAccessData(psa, &pvdata);
    memcpy(pvdata, asPostData.c_str(), asPostData.Length());
    SafeArrayUnaccessData(psa);
    TVariant vPostData(psa);
    TVariant vURL = "http://site/script.php";
    TVariant vContentType ="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8";
    zform->CppWebBrowser1->Navigate2(&vURL, TNoParam(), TNoParam(), &vPostData, &vContentType);
}
```

Запрос прекрасно отправляется, если в нем нет русских символов. Как я понимаю, *С++ Builder 5* не поддерживает юникод. Возможно ли как-то выкрутиться из этой ситуации с русскими символами и адекватно их передать?

Comment: Судя по всему надо [URL кодировать](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Comment: Внимательно почитайте спецификацию http протокола. utf-8 и юникод - это не одно и тоже.

Comment: Тип Variant поддерживает юникод.